How to open form to specific record from datasheet
I am trying to create a hyperlink in a sub-form (datasheet) to open a new form based on the record clicked on. The field that I have users click on is the result of a query.
My database has two tables Events and Owners of events. My events are listed in a datasheet with the event owners listed by name. I want to click on the event owner in the data sheet and open the Owners form to that owner.
I have tried various ways to reference to appropriate OwnerID, however, I can't seem to store it. My Owner form does not open to the specified record. This is the current code.
Private Sub OwnerName_Click()
    Dim recID As Integer
    Dim FrmParent As Form
    
    'How do I get the ID of this owner?
    recID = Me.[EventsAll]!OwnerID
    Debug.Print "recID = " & recID
    
    Set FrmParent = Forms![EventsParent]
    Debug.Print "FrmParent name = " & FrmParent.Name
    DoCmd.Close acForm, FrmParent.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Owner", , "ID = " & recID
End Sub






I would suggest the following lines:  . . . DoCmd.Close acForm, "Owner" ;  DoEvents  ;   DoCmd.Close acForm, FrmParent.Name . . ..   (replace the ; with an enter.)

A separate issue: WhereCondition is the 4th argument to OpenForm, so include another comma like this DoCmd.OpenForm "Owner", , , "ID = " & recID or use the argument name like this DoCmd.OpenForm "Owner", WhereCondition:="ID = " & recID

Which line of the procedure triggers that 2465 error?

There error is coming up on this line recID = Me.[EventsAll]!OwnerID

Does Me!OwnerID give you what you want without error?

Yep, between Me!OwnerID and the additional comma, it is working now.

Since you reported that Access objected to Me.[EventsAll]!OwnerID in the click event procedure, and since that procedure is apparently run from the EventsAll subform, reference the target value directly as Me!OwnerID
WhereCondition is the 4th argument to OpenForm, but your example puts it in the 3rd position.  You can include another comma in the argument list or use the argument name and eliminate the placeholder commas.
Private Sub OwnerName_Click()
    Dim recID As Long
    
    recID = Me!OwnerID
    Debug.Print "recID = " & recID
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Owner", , , "ID = " & recID
    '    or use the argument name like this 
    'DoCmd.OpenForm "Owner", WhereCondition:="ID = " & recID 

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "EventsParent"

End Sub

I also changed the way the parent form is closed.  When you know the name of an open form you want to close, you don't have to first set an object variable; you can just give the form name to DoCmd.Close
